# What is the alternative for virtual (Mongoose) in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

Error by compilation.
Source code can be viewed here: https://codeshare.io/GAlzEa

`node index.js
C:\Users\..\server\models\User.js:39
    User.virtual('isLocked').get(function(){
         ^
TypeError: User.virtual is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\plisam\test-master-projekt\masterprojekt\fuldaflats\server\models\User.js:39:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\plisam\test-master-projekt\masterprojekt\fuldaflats\server\models.js:18:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\plisam\test-master-projekt\masterprojekt\fuldaflats\server\endpoints.js:11:14)`